# How do I connect to Azure blob storage on Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, azure, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I would like to connect my app to the Azure blob storage. I already made a "demo" app where I created my azure proxy class. Now I want to use this class in my WinRT app. But the app targets Windows 8.1. So when I try to add the Windows Azure Storage Nuget package I get this error:

*"Could not install package 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 2.0.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."*

Do I really have to wait for the updated version or is there any other way how I can connect to the blob storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the reference using `Package Manager Console` and typing the following command:

```
Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage-Preview -Pre
```

You may need to update the package manager (I had to do that on my computer).